Is it possible to have a linked list in a list node?
Java linked list API not allowed.
Is it possible to have a linked list inside a list node? If yes, how do I insert data into the linked list that is in the list node?
List Node class (I tried to add a new linked list into the list node which worked I guess?):
public class ListNode {
    public Object data;   
    public ListNode next;
    public LinkedList testLL;
    // for normal only head/tails
    public ListNode(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.testLL = null;
    }

    // for normal nodes in the middle
    public ListNode(Object data, ListNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.testLL = null;
    }

    // for nodes that are only head/tails with a linked list extending outward
    public ListNode(Object data, LinkedList testLL) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.testLL = testLL;
    }

    // for nodes in the middle with a linked list extending outward
    public ListNode(Object data, ListNode next, LinkedList testLL) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.testLL = testLL;
    }
}

Linked list code:
public class LinkedList {
    private ListNode head;
    private ListNode tail;
    private Comparator comparator;
    private int count = 0;
    private LinkedList test;

    public LinkedList(Comparator comparator) {
        head = tail = null;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (head==null);
    }

    public void addToHead(Object item) {
        count++;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = tail = new ListNode(item, test);
        } else {
            head = new ListNode(item, head, test);
        }
    }

    public void addToTail(Object item) {
        count++;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = tail = new ListNode(item, test);
        } else {
            tail.next = new ListNode(item, test);
            tail =  tail.next;
        }
    }

    public Object removeFromHead() throws EmptyListException {
        Object item = null;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyListException();
        } 
        item = head.data;
        if (head == tail)      // there's only one single node
            head = tail = null;
        else
            head = head.next;
        count--;
        return item;

    }

    public Object removeFromTail() throws EmptyListException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyListException();
        } 
        Object item = tail.data;
        if (head == tail) {   // there is only one node
            head = tail = null;
            return item;
        }
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current.next != tail)
            current = current.next;
        tail = current;
        tail.next = null;
        count--;
        return item;
    }

    // removes duplicate nodes
    public void removeDuplicate() throws EmptyListException {
        ListNode current = head;
        ListNode checker = current.next;
        iterateLL:
        while (current.next != null) {
            // start from head, check data one by one until the data is not the same,
            // then go to that data and connect it to current
            checkRepeated:
            while(checker != null){
                if(checker.data.equals(current.data)){
                    if(checker.next == null){
                        current.next = null;
                        break iterateLL;
                    }
                    else{
                        checker = checker.next;
                        continue checkRepeated;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    current.next = checker;
                    current = current.next;
                    checker = current.next;
                    break checkRepeated;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString1() { // original toString method, will not be changed, for backup if anything messed up
        String s = "[ ";
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            s += current.data + " ";
            current = current.next;
        }
        return s + "]";
    }

    public String toString2() {
        ListNode current = head;
        String s = "\nIdentifiers found:";
        while (current != null) {
            // start from head, check data one by one until the data is not the same,
            // then go to that data and input it into String s
            s += "\n" + current.data + current.testLL.toString1();
            current = current.next;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    public void insertInOrder (Object item) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = tail = new ListNode (item);
            count++;
        } else {
            if (comparator.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(head.data, item)) {
                addToHead(item);
            } else if (comparator.isLessThanOrEqualTo(tail.data, item)) {
                addToTail(item);
            } else {
                // insert in the middle
                ListNode current = head;
                while (current.next != null) {
                    if (comparator.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(current.next.data, item)) {
                        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(item, test);
                        newNode.next = current.next;
                        current.next = newNode;
                        count++;
                        return;
                    }
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeItem (Object item) throws ItemNotFoundException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        } 
        if (comparator.isEqualTo(head.data, item)) 
            removeFromHead();
        else if (comparator.isEqualTo(tail.data, item)) 
            removeFromTail();
        else {
            // remove a node in the middle
            ListNode current = head;
            while (current.next != null) {
                if (comparator.isEqualTo(current.next.data, item)) {
                    current.next = current.next.next;
                    count--;
                    return;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        }
    }   
}

The exceptions are custom exceptions and the comparator is used to make the linked list sorted
The toString2 method will have error in the main program since it says that the linked list in the list node is null, which I don't know how to input data into the linked list in list node

A node shouldn't store a list, unless you have a List<List<...>>, at which point it should treat the List<...> objects it gets just like any other Object. Note that Object#toString is a method shared by all objects, but #toString1 and #toString2 are your own custom methods that not every object shares. What you really need is to only override/use #toString.

In short: yes, if a node can contain an object of any type, then that type can be LinkedList.
Some improvements you might consider:

Use generics to parameterise your list, improving type safety and removing the need to cast each element from Object.
Include some methods such as getHead() and getTail() to access these nodes without needing to remove them.
Include a zero-argument constructor that defines a default comparator.


What if the list node has data on its own and I want to have a linked list on the side? Like a list node contains a String Object "a" and a linked list of [1, 2, 3]

In that case you might define a class Pair<T,U> to serve as a container for two object references, then use LinkedList<Pair<String, LinkedList<Integer>>>.
